# Checking user roles in rspec FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have two user roles and i want to write a test in rspec to see if the user role are attached to the user after creation. Also admins should be able to switch the user roles from one to the other.

Here is my user model how i structure the type of users using a enum

```
 enum role: [:batman, :superman]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  protected 

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :batman
  end
```

I am stuck on the test below and not sure how to go about checking the if the role was successfully attached. Also is there a way to check if the user role can be changed for a user? For example if the user was created with the role of batman, it can be switch to superman?

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  before do
    @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
  end

  describe "creation" do
    it "can be created" do
      expect(@user).to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand you right, but I think you need something like `expect(@user.role).to be(:batman)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write expectations for model fields too. Code is pretty self-explanatory:

```rb
let(:user){ create(:user) }

it "has role batman" do
  expect(user.role).to eq("batman")
end
```

For changing:

```rb
it "changes role" do
  expect{
    do_something_with(user)
  }.to change{ user.reload.role }.from("batman").to("superman")
end
```

`reload` might be not needed in model tests, but usually is for other (request/system/etc) where record can change in db but not in exact instance in memory.

Comment: You are right reload is not needed. Sorry new to rspec. Im getting an 'undefined method `do_something_with''?

Comment: I think @Vashed meant that `do_something_with` is just pseudocode for something you want to check, like changing a role or something else

Comment: @AndyWalker replace that with method that you’re testing that should change role